# Error when creating dynamic data source in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a dynamic data source in SSRS. I have a generic report that needs to be run across multiple database servers, requiring a way to connect to each based on a parameter.

I have setup my parameters in a way where I can generate the following connection string:

```
Data Source=172.16.1.111;Initial Catalog=TESTDB
```

If I plug that connection string into the "Connection String" text area field in the Data Source Properties window and click "Test Connection," I get the "Connection created successfully" message.

However, if I attempt to create an expression with the same data source (forget about the dynamic data source for a minute), like as shown below, I get a "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized" error message when trying to test the connection.

```
="Data Source=172.16.1.111;Initial Catalog=TESTDB"
```

Based on other examples I have seen looking this up online, this type of connection string definition is supposed to work.

My end goal is to create something like:

```
="Data Source=" + Parameter!Server.Value + ";Initial Catalog=" + Parameter!Database.Value
```

which would allow me to connect to any database based on the user selection.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong? I am using SQL Server 2014 Report Builder.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with the report builder. Once I deployed the report I was able to get this work. For some reason, even if you hard code the connection string as I mentioned above, expressions will not evaluate at runtime when running from within the report builder.

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: I use an embedded data source with a connection string parameter. The web app that runs a report will tell the report which DB to use.

It is annoying that Report Builder and Visual Studio are not able to evaluate expressions at design time. The lack of this feature means that I have to update the data source connection string to text (instead of an expression) if I need to refresh data set fields. This just sucks, because if I forget to change it back to an expression before I deploy, it will go out to PROD with the wrong data source.